# Migration with unique column for certain condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration

Can I add uniqueness for a column for a certain condition (on some other column in the table)?

i.e.

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name1, [:unique => true, where: :column_name2 = false]
```

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but the concept you're doing is wrong.

When you add the unique => true in the table it will ALWAYS validate the uniqueness on database. If it is conditional than you shouldn't do it. On those cases what you need to do is create a validation on the model and not on database, like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

You can read more about it here [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But... If two request are made at the same time, the validation will be skipped: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html (Concurrency and integrity). I need the condition on the db.

Comment: In practice the chance of that happening is very small, but I've found this answer here that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321836/how-to-add-index-conditionally

Comment: The chance is big if you have users that like to spam click buttons and a process on a request that takes longer than a user can spam click (a common situation in my experience). The answer @AnezioCampos linked to in his comment has a way to handle things if you're on Postgres.